# How to lowercase second letter onwards in a string within a data frame/tibble

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(cell_type = c("Best4+ Enterocytes", "Cycling TA", 
"E.Absorptive"), marker_genes = c("OTOP3", "E2F7", "REN")), row.names = c(NA,  -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

It looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  cell_type          marker_genes
  <chr>              <chr>       
1 Best4+ Enterocytes OTOP3       
2 Cycling TA         E2F7        
3 E.Absorptive       REN
```

What I want to do is to lower case the string from `marker_genes`, but
from second letter onwards, resulting in this (done by hand):

```
  cell_type          marker_genes  
1 Best4+ Enterocytes Otop3       
2 Cycling TA         E2f7        
3 E.Absorptive       Ren
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function in `stringr` for this

```
stringr::str_to_title(df$marker_genes)
#[1] "Otop3" "E2f7"  "Ren"
```

Or the `stringi` equivalent

```
stringi::stri_trans_totitle(df$marker_genes)
```

To use it in pipes, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(marker_genes = stringr::str_to_title(marker_genes))
```

Comment: how can we apply that using dplyr piping.